# How to pass data between UIViewControllers with protocols/delegates

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols, pass-data

In the code below I have a `ViewController`("SenderViewController"), which passes a message to the main `ViewController` when a button is tapped. What I don't fully understand is how does `messageData()` method in the main `ViewController` know when to listen for the message.

Can someone please explain me what is triggering the `messageData()` method in the main `ViewController`?

SenderViewController:

```
import UIKit  
protocol SenderViewControllerDelegate {  
    func messageData(data: AnyObject)  
}  
class SenderViewController: UIViewController {  
    @IBOutlet weak var inputMessage: UITextField!  
     var delegate: SenderViewControllerDelegate?  

    @IBAction func sendData(sender: AnyObject) {  
        /  
        if inputMessage.text != ""{  
            self.presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)  
            self.delegate?.messageData(inputMessage.text!)  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Main ViewController:

```
import UIKit  
class ViewController: UIViewController, SenderViewControllerDelegate{  
    @IBOutlet weak var showData: UILabel!  

    override func viewDidLoad() {  
        super.viewDidLoad()  
    }  

    @IBAction func goToView(sender: AnyObject) {  
        let pvc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("senderViewController") as! SenderViewController  
        pvc.delegate = self  
        self.presentViewController(pvc, animated:true, completion:nil)  
    }  

   // What triggers this method, how it know when to listen? 
    func messageData(data: AnyObject) {  
        self.showData.text = "\(data)"  
    }  
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This call `self.delegate?.messageData` from `func sendData` in `SenderViewController ` is executing it.

Comment: Follow this tutorial, you will get your answer - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm

Comment: Passing data using delegate swift 4.0 : https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2017/11/what-is-protocol-how-to-pop-data-using.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objects don't exactly listen for method calls. They sit there, waiting to invoked.

The line

```
self.delegate?.messageData(inputMessage.text!)
```

From your `SenderViewController` is a function call. (The term method and function are pretty much interchangeable, although the `method` is usually used for the functions of objects.) It invokes the function messageData in `ViewController`.

Answer (score 3):

While Presenting `SenderViewController` from `MainViewController` you are setting the delegate as `self`. So whenever you call the delegate method in SenderViewController

```
self.delegate?.messageData(inputMessage.text!)
```

following method of `MainViewController` will act as a callback

```
func messageData(data: AnyObject) {  
        self.showData.text = "\(data)"  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input.

Answer (score 3):

In `SenderViewController`:

When you tap button you invoke `sendData` method. In this method you ask `delegate` to invoke its `messageData` method. Delegate property declared as `SenderViewControllerDelegate` type, so you can do that (see this protocol defenition).

In `ViewController` (first view controller):

Before you open second view controller, in method `goToView` you seting up property `delegate` of `SenderViewController` to 'myself', to exact instance of `ViewController`, since you declared that it confirm protocol `SenderViewControllerDelegate` by implementing method `messageData`. So, `ViewController` is now saved as `delegate` property in `SenderViewController`, and can be used to invoke `messageData`!

Answer (score 2):

```
self.delegate?.messageData(inputMessage.text!)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func sendData(sender: AnyObject) {  

    if inputMessage.text != ""{  
        self.delegate?.messageData(inputMessage.text!)  
        self.presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)  

    }else{
       //handle here
}
```

Note: If you need to pass multiple data to mainViewController then use dictionary to pass them. i.e.

**SenderViewController:**

```
import UIKit  
protocol SenderViewControllerDelegate {  
    func messageData(data: [String : Any])  
}  
class SenderViewController: UIViewController {  
    @IBOutlet weak var inputMessage: UITextField!  
    var delegate: SenderViewControllerDelegate?  

    @IBAction func sendData(sender: AnyObject) {  

        let myDict = [ "name": "Name", "age": 21, "email": "test@gmail.com"] as! [String : Any]

        self.delegate?.messageData(myDict) 
        self.presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)  


  }  
}
```

**Main ViewController**

```
import UIKit  
class ViewController: UIViewController, SenderViewControllerDelegate{  
    @IBOutlet weak var showData: UILabel!  

    override func viewDidLoad() {  
        super.viewDidLoad()  
    }  

    @IBAction func goToView(sender: AnyObject) {  
        let pvc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("senderViewController") as! SenderViewController  
        pvc.delegate = self  
        self.presentViewController(pvc, animated:true, completion:nil)  
    }  

   // What triggers this method, how it know when to listen? 
    func messageData(data: [String : Any]) {  
        print(data["name"])  
        print(data["age"])  
        print(data["email"])  

    }  
}
```