# Swift Send Data to a ViewController from a ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, struct, nsuserdefaults

I try to add filterview to `Viewcontroller`. I try to decide how i do but I dont know what is the best way for this implementation. Now I open a `xib` file(filterView) on the viewcontroller but also I have a tabbar and I dont align to bottom constraint to safearea because of tabbar.

Now I decide to open in new VC but I dont know how can I pass these filter datas. I think I have some method as "Observer" , "Core Data", "UserDefaults" or "Dynamic class" . Which is the best way for this question?

Can you help me for answering this question?

I dont use **Segue** also I dont want use **Segue** . I can pass data A to B but in reverse I have to apply an action in A. Also I dont want to use any function in viewDidAppear.

I open the B controller with `present(vc , animated: true)` and I get back with `dismiss(animated: true , completion: nil)`.

**This is not duplicate of any question.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215476/how-do-you-pass-data-between-view-controllers-in-swift

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721370/how-to-pass-data-between-uiviewcontrollers-with-protocols-delegates

Answer (score 0):

Let's first get in one page. you have viewController and you are presenting another viewController from code? and you want to pass data of first viewController to second one?

In your case for data passing there is no need of "user defaults" and "CoreData".

Since you are not using segues, You can simply do it by delegation or closure or using observers.

I am explaining delegation here.

for example

`Protocol DataPasser {
    func dataHolder(data: DataType)
}`

then use delegate in your first viewController like

above `ViewDidLoad()` method

`var delegate: DataPasser?`

then when redirecting next viewController just call `delegate?.dataHolder(yourData)`

and in next viewController make this delegate self and make extension to use this delegate like `extension SecondViewController: DataPasser` and use delegate method and you will have your data in delegate method argument.

Hope this will help you. if not ask me again.. here to help.

Comment: This is not my answer. I ask the choice not example. Thanks for answer.

Comment: For data passing you can use protocol, closure and NSNotificationCenter. But UserDefaults and CoreData is bad idea.

Comment: With the help of these you can pass data from anywhere to anywhere. even in backwards in your ViewController stack

Comment: I wrote also these methods. I ask which is the best way .

Comment: well that depends on your choice which looks easy to you.. i prefer you to user NSNotificationCenter.